# Corrupt picture folder

Tags: windows, images, restore, avi, jpeg

I look at my pictures in my computer today and noticed that one folder containing hundreds of picture were corrupt. I can't open the images.

- Is this a common problem?
- I wonder what possibly is behind this.
- Is there any why to fix jpg and AVI files?

I don't know if this is a hardware problem/virus or what is behind it. Please share your experience if you have had the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very unlikely that this is virus activity. Also, it's not common at all to specifically target one folder.

I would recommend running a file system check on your hard drive just to be sure no other files are corrupt, even though I don't think that is the problem.

As far as your damaged files are concerned, there's little that can be done to recover damaged images and videos. If you don't still have the source (I assume it was a memory stick from a camera), and you don't have any backups, you may be out of luck.

For what it's worth, I've had corrupt photos on my camera's memory stick, which of course get carried over as corrupt to my computer, and there's no chance of recovery because the problem was on the stick itself.

Good luck!